# Solo Interceptor PvP - Afterburners vs. MWDs

Tags: eve-online

Interceptors provide bonuses for microwarpdrives.  However, I'm worried about using them for solo PvP because they can be scrambled.  Should I downgrade to an afterburner and play it safe, or is the threat of scrambling negligible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scramming is a tactic usually relegated to squads.   If you're going to be going up against someone running Damps or some other tactic that's trying to get you in close, then I'd avoid the fight.   You lose such an incredible speed advantage by going to AB that you may have to change your tactics altogether.

On the other hand your signature radius is much smaller in an afterburner kit so you're harder to hit, not to mention the fitting you can manage with only an AB.

Ultimately if you're not a sniping cepter the risk vs reward is pretty high to stick to the MWD.  But again, it all depends on who you're fighting.  You can build up a pretty incredible transversal velocity with an MWD and those turret folks seem to hate that if you are good at zig zagging.  If you're used to the MWD and you switch to AB I'd definitely consider practising *A LOT* so you get used to the differences and when/where your proverbial hitbox is the largest.

Comment: Usually (but not necessarily all the time) when you have fit an MWD, you want to stay out of scrambler range (10k for T2, up to maybe ~18k or something like that for officer modules with overheating). It is still possible for some frigates to be able to "jink" using manual piloting and catch you if you just press the orbit button and leave it, so you have to stay aware of what the other pilot is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Just as camster342 said, It's extremely hard (and dangerous) for a inty to maintain a safe distance with another frigate when orbiting that frigate.

I would suggest using a dual-prop fit like [this battleclinic fit](http://eve.battleclinic.com/loadout/39448-Taranis-Cheap-Dual-Prop.html).

And, it's somehow old to solo in an inty...